# Getting error while compiling jackson library code

Tags: java, dropwizard

I am getting this error while upgrading the Dropwizard version from 0.9.1 to 1.3.7.
The YAML file seems to internally not being read.. Could anyone tell me the appropriate way to resolve this?
FYI: there is one internal module which has an object mapper of different version and while debugging the code it seem to redirect toward degraded Object mapper
I have added the Gradle File :

```
 configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j'
        all*.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
        all*.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-simple'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.yammer.dropwizard', module: 'dropwizard-core'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.yammer.dropwizard', module: 'dropwizard-jdbi'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.yammer.dropwizard', module: 'dropwizard-metrics-graphite'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.yammer.dropwizard', module: 'dropwizard-testing'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.yammer.metrics', module: 'metrics-core'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.yammer.metrics', module: 'metrics-graphite'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.yammer.metrics', module: 'metrics-annotation'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.yammer.metrics', module: 'metrics-jvm'

//        all*.exclude group: 'com.codahale.metrics'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.sun.jersey', module: 'jersey-core'
        all*.exclude group: 'javax.ws.rs', module: 'jsr311-api'
//        all*.exclude group: 'org.flipkart', module: 'dss-auth-client:com.fasterxml.jackson'
//        all*.exclude group: 'io.dropwizard.metrics', module: 'metrics-core'
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.fasterxml:classmate:1.5.1'
        compile 'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:' + dropwizardVersion,
                'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-metrics-graphite:' + dropwizardVersion,
                'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jdbi:' + dropwizardVersion,
                'io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:' + dropwizardMetric,
                'io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:' + dropwizardMetric,
                'io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-annotation:' + dropwizardMetric,
                'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-validation:' + dropwizardVersion,
                'com.palominolabs.metrics:metrics-guice:4.0.0' ,
//                'ru.vyarus:dropwizard-guicey:4.0.1'
        compile('com.hubspot.dropwizard:dropwizard-guice:' + '1.3.5.0') {
            exclude group: 'com.google.inject', module: 'guice_servlet'

        }
        compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:' + lombokVersion

      
                

//        compile 'com.google.inject:guice:' + guiceVersion,
//                'com.google.inject.extensions:guice-persist:' + guiceVersion

        compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.35',
                'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.5.Final'

        compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.9.4'
        compile(group: 'org.quartz-scheduler', name: 'quartz', version: '2.2.1')
        
            exclude group: 'com.yammer.dropwizard'
            exclude group: 'com.sun.jersey'
            exclude group: 'javax.ws.rs', module: 'jsr311-api'
            exclude group: 'io.dropwizard'
        }

        compile 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:' + modelMapperVersion,
                'org.modelmapper.extensions:modelmapper-guice:' + modelMapperVersion
       
        
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:' + jacksonVersion
       

        testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
        testCompile 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.191',
                    'org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.4',
                    'io.dropwizard.modules:dropwizard-flyway:0.7.0-1',
                    'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-testing:' + dropwizardVersion
        testCompile 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:6.0.8'

        testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '1.6.6'
        testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-easymock', version: '1.6.6'
        testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito', version: '1.6.6'
```

````
java.lang.VerifyError: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty$Delegating overrides final method getDeclaringClass.()Ljava/lang/Class;
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.deser.PropertyMutatorCollector.addObjectSetter(PropertyMutatorCollector.java:65)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.deser.DeserializerModifier.findOptimizableProperties(DeserializerModifier.java:140)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.deser.DeserializerModifier.updateBuilder(DeserializerModifier.java:58)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:237)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:141)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:406)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:352)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:475)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:3890)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3756)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2090)
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.BaseConfigurationFactory.build(BaseConfigurationFactory.java:127)
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.BaseConfigurationFactory.build(BaseConfigurationFactory.java:89)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.parseConfiguration(ConfiguredCommand.java:126)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:74)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)```
````

Comment: This is always a dependency version mismatch.  Your dependency is older than the code you're compiling, and in the older version that method is final and not overridable.

Comment: So How should i proceed for this @Jim